# Bash: String substitution/shorten of string with RegEx (RegEx Fail)

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I would like to shorten strings with Bash. Unfortunately this does not work as planned. I would like to have only the front part with the letters. It has unfortunately one of the variants below still works similar. How must it be written correctly?

```
var="backup_user-data_2101220046.tgz"

var2="${var/_[0-9]{10}.tgz/''}"
var2="${var/'\_[0-9]+\.tgz'/''}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `${var/pattern/replacement}` ksh93 operator, pattern is interpreted as a shell wildcard pattern, not a regexp.

In ksh93, you can switch to basic, extended or augmented regexps with `~(G)`, `~(E)`, `~(X)` respectively, so you could do:

```
var2=${var/~(E)_[0-9]{10}\.tgz$/}
```

For instance. Or use its extended glob patterns:

```
var2=${var/%_{10}([0-9]).tgz/}
```

(same as `var2=${var%%_{10}([0-9]).tgz}`)

`bash`, like `zsh` did copy the `${var/pattern/replacement}` operator from ksh93, but its wildcard operators are much more limited. With the `extglob` option enabled, it supports the extended operators of `ksh88`, but not the more advanced ones of ksh93 and in particular, not the `{x,y}(...)` one.

It does support the `+(...)` one though. So you could do:

```
shopt -s extglob
var2=${var/%_+([0-9]).tgz/}
```

In `bash`, for extended regexp support, you can use the `=~` operator of its `[[...]]` construct:

```
regexp='^(.*)_[0-9]{10}\.tgz$'
if [[ $var =~ $regexp ]]; then
  var2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  var2=$var1
fi
```

For completeness, while `zsh` did copy ksh93's `${var/pattern/replacement}` and supports the ksh88 wildcard extensions with the `kshglob` option, it has its own extended glob operators with the `extendedglob` option. With those the equivalent of ERE `{x,y}` is `(#cx,y)`, so you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob
var2=${var/%_[0-9](#c10).tgz}
```

(note that of the three shell, `zsh` is the only one where `[0-9]` matches only on 0123456789. ksh93 and bash typically match on thousand more characters such as ⑱, , etc in modern locales).

In `zsh`, you can  do regexp matching with `=~` as well. That's ERE by default but can be changed to PCRE with the `rematchpcre` option.

```
set -o rematchpcre
if [[ $var =~ '^(.*)_\d{10}\.tgz\z' ]]; then
  var2=$match[1]
else
  var2=$var
fi
```

(with ERE or PCRE whether `\d` or `[0-9]` match on 0123456789 only or not depends on the locale and the system's regexp library used by zsh, like in bash).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only "backup_user-data":

```
$ var="backup_user-data_2101220046.tgz"
$ echo "${var%_*}"
backup_user-data
```